# Как исключить в htaccess ситуацию, когда при использовании mod_rewrite запрос проходит два цикла?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Не уверен, что верно выразился в заголовке, поясню.

Есть такой `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d // 0
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f // 0
    RewriteRule ^(api/)(.*)$ api.php?_url=/$2 [QSA,L] // 1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(api.php)(.*)$ // 2
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L] // 3
</IfModule>
```

В нем происходит следующее:

Если запрос к сайту не выглядит как `http://blah.com/api/blah` (1), и не просит выдать ему реальный файл или каталог (0), а также не содержит в себе обращение к файлу api.php (2) то этот запрос переадресуется к файлу `index.php` (3), который получает в параметре `_url` всю изначальную строку запроса.

Но если наш запрос все-таки содержит из серии `http://blah.com/api/blah`, то он уже переадресуется к файлу `api.php` (1), после чего, на первый взгляд, из-за флага `L` у нас обработка запроса должна остановиться. Однако, тут стоит учесть, что в этот момент наш запрос меняется и заново приходит к нашему серверу, запрашивая уже существующий файл `api.php`, при этом не содержа `api/`, а значит у нас не выполнится условие (1), и обработка запроса дошла бы до директивы (3), если бы не условие (2), где мы говорим, что условие (3) должно выполняться во всех случаях, кроме тех, когда происходит обращение к файлу `api.php`.

Вроде бы все верно, согласны? Но есть один нюанс. Вот содержимое файлов `api.php` и `index.php`:

```
<?php
sleep(2);
fwrite(fopen('api.check', 'a'), '1');
exit;

<?php
sleep(2);
fwrite(fopen('index.check', 'a'), '1');
exit;
```

И при попытке открыть адрес вида `http://blah.com/api/blah` мы вдруг обнаруживаем, что в корне сайта создается оба файла, и `api.check` и `index.check`. Обращу ваше внимание, что не смотря на `sleep(2)`, оба файла имеют одинаковое время их создания.

**Внимание, вопрос:** на каком этапе обработки `.htaccess` все-таки происходит обращение к файлу index.php?

**UPD:** В общем, я почти нашел, каким образом решить свою проблему:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(api.php)(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(api/)(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(api/)(.*)$ api.php?_url=/$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

В этом случае при запросе к `api/` создается только файл `api.check`, с одной единицей в нем, а при запросе, не содержащем `api/`, создается только один файл `index.check`, правда, с два раза записанным в него единицей, что означает, что запрос к файлу происходит все-таки дважды, что на самом деле тоже не верно.

Однако, ответ на вопрос "почему происходит в разных случаях так, а не иначе", я не получил, плюс двойное обращение к `index.php` тоже совершенно не здорово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался достаточно неожиданным: оказывается, Google Chrome хотел получить файл `favicon.ico`, который естественно у меня не был создан, в связи с чем `.htaccess` считал этот запрос достойным того, чтобы переадресовать его на файл `index.php`. В целом, это не стало бы в будущем проблемой, так как в случае реально написанного бекенда он обрабатывал бы 404-ошибки и выдавал бы просто соответствующий отлуп браузеру, не выполняя лишнего кода, но тем не менее, стоит иметь такое поведение браузера ввиду.